# Is the sequence $a_n = \left(\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\right)$ decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is the sequence $a_n = \left(\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\right)$ decreasing?

I tried to find whether $a_{n+1} < a_n$. That is,

\begin{align*}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}} &< \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\\
(n+1)^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}&>n^{1+\frac{1}{n}} \\
(n+1)^{\frac{n+2}{n+1}}&>n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}
\end{align*}

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I thought if the sequence is indeed decreasing, I could potentially find that for the statement to be false, it must be that $n < 1$. However, I am not sure if that is true or how I would show that to be the case.

I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
(n+1)^{\frac{n+2}{n+1}}&>n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\\
(n+1)^{(n+2)n}&>n^{(n+1)^2}\\
(n+1)^{n^2+2n}&>n^{n^2+2n+1}\\
(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2+2n}&>n\\
\end{align*}$$

Now use Bernoulli:
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2+2n} \geq 1+ (n^2+n)\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, we may ask if the sequence given by $n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ is increasing, or the sequence given by $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\log(n)$ is increasing. The latter is increasing for sure, since:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\log x = \frac{x+1-\log x}{x^2} $$
and the RHS is $\geq \frac{2}{x^2}$ for any $x\geq 1$.